# cannot install Catalyst 5.9 on Windows 10

Tags: perl, catalyst, strawberry-perl

This is another attempt to be more direct with my question. I am having extreme difficult getting Strawberry Perl 5.22 64bit on Windows 10 ready for simple web development.

I first started with `cpanm Catalyst::Devel` and that failed to install a group of dependencies:

```
==> Found dependencies: Plack::Test, Plack::Builder, Plack::Middleware, Plack::Util
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Plack::Test' is not installed, Module 'Plack::Middleware' is not installed, Module 'Plack::Builder' is not installed, Module 'Plack::Util' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for Plack-Middleware-RemoveRedundantBody-0.05.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Plack::Middleware::IIS6ScriptNameFix' is not installed, Module 'Plack::Middleware::ContentLength' is not installed, Module 'Plack::Test::ExternalServer' is not installed, Module 'Plack::Middleware::HTTPExceptions' is not installed, Module 'Plack::Middleware::ReverseProxy' is not installed, Module 'Plack::Middleware::MethodOverride' is not installed, Module 'Plack::Request::Upload' is not installed, Module 'Plack::Middleware::FixMissingBodyInRedirect' is not installed, Module 'Plack::Middleware::LighttpdScriptNameFix' is not installed, Module 'Plack::Middleware::RemoveRedundantBody' is not installed, Module 'Plack::Middleware::Conditional' is not installed, Module 'Plack::Middleware::Head' is not installed, Module 'Plack' is not installed, Module 'Plack::Middleware::IIS7KeepAliveFix' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for Catalyst-Runtime-5.90103.
```

And since Plack seemed to be a culprit I ran `cpan Plack` which led to this error report:

```
t/01_simple.t                (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 2 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  2
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/11_net_empty_port.t        (Wstat: 256 Tests: 4 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  4
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=14, Tests=117, 87 wallclock secs ( 0.08 usr +  0.05 sys =  0.12 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/14 test programs. 2/117 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
  TOKUHIROM/Test-TCP-2.14.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports TOKUHIROM/Test-TCP-2.14.tar.gz
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Test::TCP'.
```

This is output for `cpan Test::TCP`:

```
C:\Strawberry>cpan Test::TCP
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.211)
Database was generated on Thu, 14 Jan 2016 18:19:06 GMT  
Running install for module 'Test::TCP'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.95)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.069)
Checksum for C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\T\TO\TOKUHIROM\Test-TCP-2.14.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v2.04)
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.2304)
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.59)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.4417)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150005)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20151220)
Configuring T/TO/TOKUHIROM/Test-TCP-2.14.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Test::TCP
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  TOKUHIROM/Test-TCP-2.14.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for T/TO/TOKUHIROM/Test-TCP-2.14.tar.gz
cp lib/Test/TCP.pm blib\lib\Test\TCP.pm
cp lib/Test/TCP/CheckPort.pm blib\lib\Test\TCP\CheckPort.pm
cp lib/Net/EmptyPort.pm blib\lib\Net\EmptyPort.pm
  TOKUHIROM/Test-TCP-2.14.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/00_compile.t ................. 1/1 # Test::More: 1.001014
t/00_compile.t ................. ok
t/01_simple.t .................. 1/? cannot open port: ::1:51108 at C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\Test-TCP-2.14-tzPh8E\blib\lib/Test/TCP.pm line 54.
    # Child (v6) exited without calling finalize()
#   Failed test 'v6'
t/01_simple.t .................. 2/? #   at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/Test/Builder.pm line 279.
# Tests were run but no plan was declared and done_testing() was not seen.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 2.
t/01_simple.t .................. Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 1/2 subtests
t/02_abrt.t .................... skipped: win32 doesn't support embedded function named dump()
t/03_return_when_sigterm.t ..... ok
t/04_die.t ..................... ok
t/05_sigint.t .................. skipped: this test requires SIGUSR1
t/06_nest.t .................... ok
t/07_optional.t ................ ok
t/08_exit.t .................... ok
t/09_fork.t .................... ok
t/10_oo.t ...................... ok
t/11_net_empty_port.t .......... 3/?
    #   Failed test 'port is open'
    #   at t/11_net_empty_port.t line 22.
    # Looks like you failed 1 test of 4.
    #   Failed test 'v6'
t/11_net_empty_port.t .......... 4/? #   at t/11_net_empty_port.t line 37.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 4.
t/11_net_empty_port.t .......... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/4 subtests
t/12_pass_wait_port_options.t .. ok
t/13_undef_port.t .............. ok
Test Summary Report
t/01_simple.t                (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 2 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  2
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/11_net_empty_port.t        (Wstat: 256 Tests: 4 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  4
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=14, Tests=117, 88 wallclock secs ( 0.05 usr +  0.02 sys =  0.06 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/14 test programs. 2/117 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
  TOKUHIROM/Test-TCP-2.14.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports TOKUHIROM/Test-TCP-2.14.tar.gz
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Test::TCP'.
```

Comment: I'm curious if Test::TCP is failing for the same reason as in [this ticket](https://github.com/tokuhirom/Test-TCP/issues/37). Can you run `cpan Test::TCP` and edit the full test output into your question?

Comment: v6 error does look similar but how do I apply that patch?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like a [different ticket](https://github.com/tokuhirom/Test-TCP/issues/43) with what seems to be the same issue is still open, and is happening even with the latest version of Test::TCP (2.14).